# replace NA's with 0, and Non NA's with a different value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
my_df <- data.frame(
    ID = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18), 
    b2 = c(NA, 4, 6, 2, NA, 6, 1, 1, NA))
```

and, I want to replace all NA's with '0', and every other values (Non-NA's) with '1', and place them in a new column (b4)

I can replace only NA's with 0 using this:

```
my_df2 <- my_df %>%
    mutate(b3 = replace(b2,is.na(b2),0))
```

I would have thought I can use below step to then replace other values (Non-NA's) with '1':

```
my_df3 <- my_df2 %>% mutate(b4=ifelse(b3=="NA","0","1"))
```

This however, does not work the way I anticipated. Perhaps how to get through this in one go.
Any advice with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `NA` properly here -- you are treating it like a character variable in `x=="NA"` - with `NA` values, standard practice is to use `is.na()`, not `x==NA`. Try:

```
my_df$b3 <- ifelse(is.na(my_df$b2), 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the code in the question is that comparing to "NA" is not the same as checking if the value is NA.  What that is doing is comparing the value to a character string which contains N and A.  Also note that comparing to NA always gives NA so we can't use that either.  Instead use `is.na`.

```
my_df$b2 == "NA"
## [1]    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA

my_df$b2 == NA
## [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

is.na(my_df$b2)
## [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Now, since coercing TRUE and FALSE to numeric gives 1 and 0 respectively,

```
+TRUE
## [1] 1

+FALSE
## [1] 0
```

we can compute `!is.na(b2)` which is TRUE if it is not NA and FALSE if it is and then convert that to numeric using + to give the 0/1 value needed.

```
my_df %>% mutate(b3 = +!is.na(b2))
```

giving:

```
  ID b2 b3
1  2 NA  0
2  4  4  1
3  6  6  1
4  8  2  1
5 10 NA  0
6 12  6  1
7 14  1  1
8 16  1  1
9 18 NA  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find below one possible answer using the `dplyr` library

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(dplyr)

my_df %>% 
  mutate(b2 = if_else(is.na(b2), 0, 1))
```

- Output

```r
#>   ID b2
#> 1  2  0
#> 2  4  1
#> 3  6  1
#> 4  8  1
#> 5 10  0
#> 6 12  1
#> 7 14  1
#> 8 16  1
#> 9 18  0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>